# Mock the return value of a function derived from an input parameter

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I want to mock the return value of a function that derives from an input parameter (`a`).
Here is the my code looks like.

```
 def load_data(a, b, c):
     data_source = a.get_function(b, c)
     ...
     return r_1, r_2, r_3
```

This is what I tried and didn't work. I was unable to find any sources that mock the return of this type of function.

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.a = A.create()
    cls.data_needed_return = read_file()

def test_function(self):
    mocked = mock.Mock()
    self.a.get_function.return_value = self.data_needed_return

    import python_file
    data_source = python_file.load_data(None, None, None)
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question and problem correctly, but are you looking for something like the following?

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

def load_data(a, b, c):
    data_source = a.get_function(b, c)
    return data_source

a = Mock()
a.get_function.return_value = "Some data"

x = load_data(a, 2, 3)

print(x)
```

Comment: This is something I am looking for. Your solution gives a TypeError:object is not callable, not sure whether it's trying to call the function without mocking correctly

Comment: Your code is working fine! this is something I need to figure out from my end.